# bit datatype in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column "Status" of bit type in a table  and in the declaration of parameters I have defaulted it to 0 and I have few other parameters coming in with defaulted to null

```
 @FirstName varchar(20) = null,
 @LastName varchar(20) = null,
 @Status bit = 0
```

and my sql is something like

```
 Select * from customers where 
 (ISNULL(@FirstName,'') =''  OR  FirstName= @FirstName)
 AND (ISNULL(@LastName,'') =''  OR  LastName= @LastName)
 AND (Status = @Status)
```

The situation is if only @FirstName value is sent from the code and the Value of the column "Status = 1" in the table and no value for @Status is sent, then since it @Status defaults to 0 no records get returned. How to deal with the bit type, in a situation where the parameter for the bit type is not sent and the value for it in the table is 1.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking, and it doesn't help that your example code is unbalanced in terms of `()` bracketing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever added the proper brackets, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value of your `@status` parameter to `null`, as you have with your other parameters.

```
@Status bit = null
```

You can rationalise your filter by doing this

```
 where
     isnull(@firstname, Firstname) = FirstName
 and
     isnull(@LastName, LastName) = LastName
 and 
     isnull(@Status, Status) = Status
```

Both this, and your original query, won't return rows where the value in the database is null.

Comment: Even if I set it to null, the bit value defaults to false and will bring in a 0 from the code.

Comment: There's either a problem with how you're calling the procedure, or how your parameters are declared.